# How to link output and redirect input from the console towards a (multiple) Qt widget(s)

Tags: c++, qt, console, widget, output

I have built a small card game, and I am currently working on a GUI for its chat room. The chat room is a simple network program that uses sockets to connect all clients that have currently selected the chatting option.

Everything works pretty well when running the program from the console, however I wish for it to be part of the game's GUI. So I was wondering, since I'm quite inexperienced with Qt, what would be the easiest way of redirecting console output to a Qt window that would display all chat messages received since the person connected to the chat.

I want it to do something along the lines of wherever there is a line doing

```
std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
```

I want that "something" to be displayed on a Qt widget. How would I do that? What widget from the Qt Creator should I use? I thought of using QTextStream (http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTextStream_QIODevice.php), but I can't figure out how to.

I think I already know how to do the sending, so the message display is more important. Please tell me if you need any specific code, the application is pretty big so posting it all would be a bit too much.

Thank you.